# R plotly: Custom hover text does not appear when only one stacked bar

Tags: r, hover, plotly

I have been using example on custom hover text (https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/) to change hover text in barplots i'm working on. If my barplot only includes one stacked bar the new hover text doesn't show. Example (it's in the last plot where the hoverinfo is missing):

```
library(plotly)
year <- c(2015,2015,2016,2016)
type <- c('A','B','A','B')
perc <- c(10,90,20,80)

data <- data.frame(year,type,perc)

# Plot all the data ... default hoverinfo shown
plot_ly(data,x=~year,y=~perc,color=~type) %>% 
  add_bars()%>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")

# Plot all the data ... custom hoverinfo shown
plot_ly(data,x=~year,y=~perc,color=~type,
  text = ~paste('Type',type,': ',perc,'%'),hoverinfo = 'text') %>% 
  add_bars()%>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")

# Plot part of the data ... default hoverinfo shown
plot_ly(data[data$year == 2015,],x=~year,y=~perc,color=~type) %>% 
  add_bars()%>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")

# Plot part of the data ... custom hoverinfo does not appear!
plot_ly(data[data$year == 2015,],x=~year,y=~perc,color=~type,
  text = ~paste('Type',type,': ',perc,'%'),hoverinfo = 'text') %>% 
  add_bars()%>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

Using R version 3.3.2 and plotly version 4.5.6.

Answer (score 2):

Got some help and the solution is to define the text as a list.

```
plot_ly(data[data$year == 2015,],x=~year,y=~perc,color=~type,
  text = ~list(paste('Type',type,': ',perc,'%')),hoverinfo = 'text') %>% 
  add_bars()%>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

This works as long as I know there is only one bar and the order of the ~type is the same throughout the dataset. If I change the types to

```
type <- c('A','B','B','A')
```

and run

```
data <- data.frame(year,type,perc)
plot_ly(data[data$year == 2016,],x=~year,y=~perc,color=~type,
      text = ~list(paste(year,'Type',type,': ',perc,'%')),hoverinfo = 'text') %>% 
  add_bars()%>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

I don't get the right order of hoverinfo. So this is not the perfect solution.

Comment: If one looks at the generated html file it looks like the x and y are arrays but the text is not an array (if you don't add the list command) when only one x. But why plotly doesn't generate the 'text' as an array in this case I don't know.